# Enviar sólo parte de un formulario vía Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario bastante grande con varios botones para enviar peticiones diferentes al servidor vía Ajax.

Yo envío los datos a través de esta función:

```
function enviarForm() {
    var frm = $('#frm_crud');
    var data = frm.serializeArray();
    console.log(data);

    var request = 
        $.ajax({
        url: frm.prop('action'),
        method: frm.prop('method'),
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html'
        });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
    });
}
```

Ahora bien, mi código no está optimizado, ya que mi formulario sirve para muchas cosas y aquí, por cada cosa yo envío **todo** el formulario al servidor.

**Quisiera saber una posibilidad de enviar sólo parte del formulario, según la necesidad que tenga.**

**Nota:** Necesito **un solo formulario**, porque en ciertas operaciones sí es útil enviar todo el formulario al servidor. Mi formulario está concebido como una especie de escritorio a través del cual yo pueda realizar varios tipos de operaciones según mis necesidades.

Voy a poner un ejemplo muy simple, a sabiendas de que el formulario es mucho más complejo:

```
<form id="frm_crud" action="ok.php" method="post">
  <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
  <input id="idname" type="text" name="name">
  <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
  <input id="idapellido" type="text" name="apellido">
  <button id="btnPersona">Enviar Persona</button>
  <hr />
  <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
  <input id="idciudad" type="text" name="ciudad">
  <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
  <input id="idprovincia" type="text" name="provincia">
  <button id="btnGeo">Enviar Geo</button>
</form>
```

Al apretar el botón `Enviar Persona`, quisiera enviar solamente los datos relativos a esa parte del formulario (Nombre y Apellido), sin tener que especificarlos uno por uno. Una especie de `serialize` segmentado. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: a ver lo que quieres hacer es muy costoso hacerlo por ajax y javascript, lo recomendable seria que pongas varios botones, y a cada uno un name distinto, luego generas un array de los datos que deseas filtrar a ser enviados y dependiendo del botón que pulsas cargas el array , filtras los input y luego envías, este filtrado es lo que seria un poco costoso de hacer. y lo recomendable seria que hagas funciones individuales.

Comment: La solución más sencilla es crear dos formularios distintos.

Comment: @PetrusPetrōrum son varias sub partes, he puesto dos como ejemplo, pero son muchas subpartes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he logrado de esta forma:

1. Dividiendo las diferentes partes del `form` con `fieldset`.
2. Escuchando los clicks de los botones por su id.
3. **Usando [`closest('fieldset')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para recuperar solamente los datos contenidos en el fieldeset al que pertenece el botón**.
4. Pasando los datos a la función de envío del form, la cual quedaría así:

   ```
   function enviarForm(data) {
       var frm = $('#frm_crud');
       //var data = frm.serializeArray();
       console.log(data);

       var request = 
           $.ajax({
           url: frm.prop('action'),
           method: frm.prop('method'),
           data: data,
           dataType: 'html'
           });

       request.done(function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
       });

       request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
           alert('Hubo un error: ' + textStatus);
       });
   }
   ```

Aquí un fragmento de código, probando con un botón:

```js
$(function() {

    $("#btnPersona").click(function(e)  {
          var data = $(this).closest('fieldset').serialize();
          console.log(data);
          e.preventDefault();
          //enviarForm(data);
  });

    $("#btnGeo").click(function(e)  {
          var data = $(this).closest('fieldset').serialize();
          console.log(data);
          e.preventDefault();
          //enviarForm(data);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm_crud" action="ok.php" method="post">

  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input id="idname" type="text" name="name">
    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
    <input id="idapellido" type="text" name="apellido">
    <button id="btnPersona">Enviar Persona</button>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
    <input id="idciudad" type="text" name="ciudad">
    <label for="provincia">Provincia:</label>
    <input id="idprovincia" type="text" name="provincia">
    <button id="btnGeo">Enviar Geo</button>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: usa las funciones delegadas `$("#btnPersona").on('click', function() {` si llegas a cambiar algo en el formulario con ajax siga funcionando...

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la ventaja de su uso en este caso @FranciscoNúñez? Son de las cosas que no me quedan del todo claras, cuándo usar `click` o cuando usar `on.click`. Agradecería cualquier indicación aclaratoria al respecto o algún enlace. Saludos.

Comment: te recomendaria pasarte a on.('Evento delegado') ; ya que este mapea el DOM cada vez que se ejecuta la accion, sin embargo .click no lo hace y es por esto que si modificas algo mediante ajax, contenido, botones, es muy probable que lo nuevo agregado no te funcione correctamente o simplemente el evento listener no se ejecute.

Comment: este es el link de referencia bastante detallado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/4717133

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que simplifiques y hagas un formulario para cada bloque de información que quieras enviar. Para cada formulario creas un evento que capture la pulsación de su botón y redirige el flujo a la función que ya tienes. Por ejemplo:

```
$("#btnPersona").on('click', function() {
    enviarForm($(this).parent()); // Aqui ya le estas enviando el objeto form
});
```

Y perparar la función enviarForm para esperar un formulario:

```
function enviarForm(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea otro formulario que te sirva para lo que necesitas o estaras violando e[l principio de responsabilidad unica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica).

Tienes el problema de que estas utilizando un solo formulario para muchas cosas lo que indica que tu diseño va a terminar muy complejo para algo tan simple como enviar un nombre y apellido.

Ahora bien, si cuando dices que sirve para muchas cosas, como por ejemplo que requiere un auto-complete y para eso necesitas enviar el nombre/apellido/edad/etc. por separado, entonces podrias utilizar la libreria [$.serializeObject()](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject) donde te convierte el form en un objeto y solo extraes la información que necesitas sin enviar lo demás:

```
var form = $("form").serializeObject();
    $.get("url", {name:form.nombre, lastName:form.apellido}, function(response){
            //...
    })
```

Comment: En realidad es una clase bastante compleja... he puesto lo de Nombre y Apellido para que se entienda mejor. El formulario representa una entidad única, muy compleja... Y yo necesito por ejemplo actualizar una parte del formulario... o introducir claves de una parte del formulario en otras tablas relacionadas. Quiero un solo formulario que me haga todas las tareas operativas relativas a esa clase. No creo que esté violando el *principio de responsabilidad única* aún ignorando su existencia.

Answer (score 0):

la idea base seria esta:

lo que necesitas hacer es usar grep:

generas un array con los elementos del boton que pulsas:
en el onlick capturas el id del boton

```
var arr1 = [ name, apellido];
var arr2 = [ campo1, campo2];
var arr3 = [ campo3, campo4];
```

Generas un formulario virtual:

```
formData    = new FormData(),
```

haces un if para saber que funcion ejecutas:

```
if(nameboton='enviarpersona'){
    $.grep(arr1, function( n, i ) {
        var name = $(v).attr("name");
        var val = $(v).val();
        formData.append(name, val);
    });
}elseif(otro boton){
    otro bucle array
}
```

funcion ajax y envias el formData

```
data: formData,
```

Debes adaptarlo a tu necesidad

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/