# guardar radiobutton php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

tengo un formulario para poder añadir filas a una tabla
[image: formulario]
lo que no se como hacer es como recibir el campo del radioButton al momento de guardar, ya que cada uno tiene nombres diferentes en cada fila como por ejemplo

1. 1era fila ---SinPendulo0
2. 2da fila ----SinPendulo1
   ....

**Vista (parte del td de mi tabla)**

```
<td>                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="SinPedinculo${j}[]" id="SinPedinculo${j}" value="SI">
                      Si
                    </label>                      
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="SinPedinculo${j}[]" id="SinPedinculo${j}" value="NO" checked>
                      No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="GolpexJava[]" id="GolpexJava${j}" value="SI">
                      Si
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="GolpexJava[]" id="GolpexJava${j}" value="NO" checked>
                      No
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </td>
```

**Controller (parte del controller , donde recibo los campos para guardarlos)**

```
                $Recepciones->Idiccab=$Idd; 
                $Recepciones->n_item=$num_item+1;   
                $Recepciones->Color=$_REQUEST["Color"][$i]; 
                $Recepciones->Brix=$_REQUEST["Brix"][$i];   
               $Recepciones->SinPedinculo=$_REQUEST["SinPedinculo"][$i];
```

Podrian ayudarme .. gracias..

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un formulario y lo envías serializado al servidor? De ese modo te mandará todo lo que haya dentro del form.

Comment: Gracias por resonder, en realidad todo eso esta dentro de un formulario, y lo estoy enviando todo a un controller, que es el que recibe todos los campos,el codigo que pude mostrar solo es una parte, mi interrogante es, como recibo esos radiobutton en el controller, que estan dentro de la tabla

Comment: Pues tendrías que darle un nombre distinto a cada uno y recuperarlo por su etiqueta `name`, por ejemplo: `$chkUno=$_POST["chkUno"]; $chkDos=$_POST["chkDos"];`  ... suponiendo que a uno le diste: `... name="chkUno" ... `  a otro: `... name="chkDos"... ` y así sucesivamente.

Comment: claro esa es la idea, pero las filas de la tabla son creadas dinamicamente, por ejemplo, si le pongo que agregue 2 filas a la tabla, automaticamente, se crean los radios de esta forma para la 1era fila <input type="radio" name="SinPendiculo0" value='si'>Si<input type="radio" name="SinPendiculo0" value='No'>No ,  para la 2da fila <input type="radio" name="SinPendiculo1" value='si'>Si<input type="radio" name="SinPendiculo1" value='No'>No, y como el name cambia, no se como recibirlo en el controlador

Comment: Pues esto se puede hacer de varias formas, por ejemplo se me ocurre que puedes poner los checkboxes que se crean de forma dinámica dentro de un `fieldset`  del formulario, los otros datos dentro de otro `fieldset`, serializarlo de forma manual, poniendo aparte los dos grupos de datos y luego en el servidor, usas la clave del `fieldset` donde están los checkboxes para obtener todos los que fueron pasados. Aunque yo no sé si realmente deberías rediseñar tus tablas evitando tantas columnas distintas y pensando las relaciones *en vertical*, mediante una tabla pivote que maneje las relaciones.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115786/29967) en el que se recupera la información del `from` agrupada en `fieldset`. No es exactamente tu caso, pero sería cuestión de crear dos grupos de datos, luego unirlos y enviarlos al servidor, pero cada grupo de datos tendría una clave que identificaría que uno son los grupos de `checkbox` y sus valores, mientras que otro es el resto del formulario.

Comment: Gracias  .. lo revisare.. !!