# PHP- Problema al insertar datos con MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, insert

Tengo una página principal con formularios a la que, depende del submit que se pulse me saca un include. Al pulsar el submit del tercer formulario aparece el include que tiene otro formulario con el que voy a insertar filas a la base de datos. Aqui viene el problema y es que al rellenar todos los campos de este formulario y enviar no pasa nada, ni siquiera sale un mensaje de error.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Series/Peliculas</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
include ("includes/config.php");
include ("includes/funciones.php");

echo "<h2 class='title1' style=text-align:center;>Lista de series y peliculas </h2>";
echo "<hr>";
echo "<table border=3 class='menu'>";

echo "<tr><td class='title'><h2>Menú</h2></td></tr>";

//  FORMULARIOS

//FORM LSERIES
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='lseries' name='lseries' value='Lista de series vistas'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";
//FORM LPELICULAS
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='lpeliculas' name='lpeliculas' value='Lista de peliculas vistas'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";
//FORM AÑADIR SERIE  <--ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO AL QUE ME REFIERO
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='aserie' name='aserie' value='Añadir series'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";
//FORM AÑADIR PELICULA
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='apelicula' name='apelicula' value='Añadir peliculas'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";
//FORM BORRAR SERIE 
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='bserie' name='bserie' value='Borrar series'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";
//FORM BORRAR PELICULA
echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>";
echo "<tr><td><h2><input type='submit' id='bpelicula' name='bpelicula' value='Borrar peliculas'></h2></td></tr>";
echo "</form";


echo "</table>"; 


//INCLUDES

if(isset($_GET['lseries'])){
$cnx=conectar();
include("lseries.php");
mysqli_close($cnx);
}


//AQUI LLAMO A aseries.php
if(isset($_GET['aserie'])){
$cnx=conectar();
include("aseries.php");
mysqli_close($cnx);
}




?>
</center>
</body>
</html>


---------------------------------

Este es el include que da problemas.


<?php

echo "<br>";

if(isset($_GET['añadirs'])){

$campos="Nombre,Link,Nota";
$valores="'".$_GET['noms']."',";
$valores.="'".$GET_['links']."',";
$valores.="'".$GET_['notas']."'";


$aseries="INSERT INTO series ($campos) VALUES($valores)"; 
$res=mysqli_query($cnx,$aseries) or die(mysql_error());

if($res){
 echo "Serie $nombre añadida a la lista correctamente";
}
else{
 echo "No ha podido añadirse la serie";
}
}

echo "<table border=2px>";
echo "<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Link</th><th>Nota</td></tr>";
echo "<form method='GET' action='aseries.php'>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='noms' id='noms'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='links' id='links'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='number' name='notas' id='notas'></td>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='3'><input type='submit' name='añadirs' id='añadirs' value='Añadir'></td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde. Primero no es una buena practica usar el código **html** dentro del php. Lo primero que te recomiendo hacer es que imprimas con **echo** el valor **$aseries** para que veas como se esta conformando tu consulta y la ejecutes en un cliente sql para que veas si tiene algún error. Ya que hay servidores que no muestran los errores en pantalla. Si te envía algún error en el cliente que puede ser el phpmyadmin, por favor de ponerlo en tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Gracias a ambos por la respuesta. He hecho un echo a $aseries y creo que esta bien formada la consulta, este ha sido el resultado : INSERT INTO series (Nombre,Link,Nota) VALUES ('Juego de tronos','https://ver.hboespana.com',8). He tenido que hacerla justo despues de cerrar el isset por que sino no podia verla por que se enviaba el formulario. No aparece ningun mensaje de error, no se que puede estar fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Prueba la parte que dices que no funciona de este modo.

Aquí he aplicado algo que se llama *consultas preparadas*. Deberías usar esta metodología siempre que vayas a ejecutar una consulta que utilice datos externos. Mandar esos datos de forma directa podría comprometer seriamente los datos o el mismo sistema. Cuando puedas lee sobre *Inyección SQL*.

Este código controla la inserción y te informará del error que haya ocurrido, o del estado exitoso de la inserción.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Si no entiendes algo me preguntas en comentarios a la respuesta.

```
$noms      = ( empty($_GET['noms'])  )  ? NULL : $_GET['noms'];
$links     = ( empty($_GET['links']) )  ? NULL : $_GET['links'];
$notas     = ( empty($_GET['notas']) )  ? NULL : $_GET['notas'];

if( isset($_GET['añadirs']) && $noms && $links && $notas ){
    $campos="Nombre,Link,Nota";
    $aseries="INSERT INTO series ($campos) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    if ($cnx) { 
        $res=mysqli_prepare($cnx,$aseries);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($res, "ssi", $noms,$links,$notas);
        if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($res) ){
            $msgOut="Serie $noms añadida a la lista correctamente";
            mysqli_stmt_close($res);

        }else{
            $msgOut="Error: ".mysqli_error($cnx);
        }
    } else {
        $msgOut="No hay conexión";
    }       
}else{
    $msgOut="El formulario no envió los datos correctamente o hay datos vacíos";
}
echo $msgOut;
```

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida y por el consejo A.Cedano. Con este código, cuando ejecuto el formulario aserie del menu para añadir series, lo primero que aparece junto al formulario de inserción es el mensaje:"El formulario no envió los datos correctamente o hay datos vacíos", por que todavía no he escrito nada. Una vez que pulso el submit 'añadirs' me desaparece el formulario de insercion y no sale ningun mensaje de error. Como lo estoy haciendo con el metodo get,  en la barra de direcciones se puede ver como ha cogido los datos correctamente.

Comment: @Mnavarro observa que hay una condición `isset($_GET['añadirs'])` si el formulario no envía ese dato de alguna manera, no entrará en la parte de la inserción. Por cierto, evita usar letras como `ñ` .... te va a dar muchos problemas, puedes cambiar eso por una palabra en inglés cono `insert` o `addrecord` o algo así.

Comment: O sea, @Mnavarro,  prueba a cambiar el `name` del botón. En vez de `name='añadirs'` puedes poner `name='create'`  o algo parecido.  Y en PHP, cambias el `isset` poniéndolo así:   `if( isset($_GET['create']) && $noms && $links && $notas ){`  la `ñ` puede ser problemática en contextos como este.

Comment: Tendré en cuenta lo de la ñ @A.Cedano, he cambiado el nombre del submit, ahora es 'insert' y el isset es $_GET['insert'] pero el comportamiento es el mismo. Al enviar los datos ahora con el submit 'insert' sigue sin insertar nada en la base de datos.

Comment: Puede que alguno de los datos esté llegando vacío ¿? Cambia esto así: `$msgOut="El formulario no envió los datos correctamente o hay datos vacíos. Datos [Nom: $noms / Links: $links / Notas:$notas";`  debería aparecer en el mensaje cada dato al lado de los dos puntos, @Mnavarro, si falta alguno el insert no se hará.

Comment: He estado haciendo muchas pruebas y he conseguido que funcione. Lo que he hecho ha sido sacar el if(isset($_GET['create'])) fuera del otro if que sacaba el formulario. La verdad es que no entiendo por que funciona ahora.  
 } #Este es el cierre del if(isset($_GET['aserie'])) (El formulario)  
  $cnx=conectar();
  if(isset($_GET['create'])){
 $nombre=$_GET['noms'];
 $link=$_GET['links'];
 $nota=$_GET['notas'];
 $campos="Nombre,Link,Nota";
    
 $sql="INSERT INTO series ($campos) VALUES ('$nombre','$link',$nota)";
    
$cons=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);
echo $sql;
}
mysqli_close($cnx);

Comment: @Mnavarro todo eso se puede simplificar usando Ajax, así, enviarías en cada caso una clave con la acción a  realizar: Insertar, Actualizar, Borrar, Seleccionar... y ejecutarías el código de forma transparente en background sin tener que estar recargando la página. En cuanto al formulario lo puedes dividir en `fieldset` si quieres enviar partes de él según el botón que sea pulsado ([ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115786/29967)), creo que sería una solución interesante para tu caso.