# 2 eventos ajax en un mismo archivo

Tags: ajax, script

Buenas mira os cuento tengo como una especie de formulario dinámico mediante dos eventos ajax onclik
(Primer evento)al hacer el click mediante ajax hago una búsqueda en base de datos y muestra los resultados relacionados con el id del div seleccionado.

Los resultados mediante el primer evento también continúen un id para que al clicar uno de estos resultados del primer evento se ejecute el segundo.
El segundo evento seria lo mismo evento que el primero pero en otra tabla pero no me esta funcionando. al acer click en el div que continúe el data-id no hace nada, directamente no me esta enviando el formulario.
pd: los dos archivos donde hace las busquedas i muestra los resultados funcionan bien el problema creo que esta en el codigo ajax.

os dejo el script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ctg_bb_rd_circle").on("click", function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("data-v-id");
    $.ajax({
    url: "category.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id: parseInt(id)},
    success: function(respuesta){
     console.log(respuesta.responseText);
     $("#task_service").remove();
    }, error: function(respuesta){
     $("#task_service").remove();
     $("#subcategory > div").prepend(respuesta.responseText);
    }
   })
  });
  
  $(".category").on("click", function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
    url: "category-2.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id: parseInt(id)},
    success: function(respuesta){
     console.log(respuesta.responseText);
     $("#subcategory").remove();
    }, error: function(respuesta){
     $("#subcategory").remove();
     $("#results > div").prepend(respuesta.responseText);
    }
   })
  });.
```

os dejo tambien el resulto que me daria una vez ejecutado el primer click i evento. Este al hacer clic deberia de activar el segundo evento pero no activa nada

```html
<div class="categoy" data-id="25">Subcategoria</div>
```

Comment: Creo que te complicas demasiado. Puedes tener: -Un solo Ajax que apunte a  un solo archivo llamado `category.php`. -Un solo listener on click que escuche a los dos botones  ... ¿Dónde se marca la diferencia? En el atributo `data` que mandas vía Ajax. Según el botón que sea pulsado pones un identificador en `data` y luego en `category.php` buscas si ese identificador está y ejecutas el bloque de código correspondiente. No necesitas para este caso dos Ajax, dos archivos y dos manejos de respuestas que no hacen otra cosa que complicarte la existencia.

Comment: podrias mostrarme un ejemplo de como hacerlo? piensa que los dos archivos de category y category-2 son consultas a diferentes tablas y con diferentes resultados

Comment: El ejemplo más claro que tengo a mano [es este]. En ese código los datos se postean al mismo archivo. Ahí por ejemplo yo capturo los datos por grupo, habiéndolos separado en el formulario en `fieldset`. Cuando se hace click en cualquiera de los dos botones verás en la consola que se mandarían al servidor sólo los datos de la parte perteneciente a ese botón. En cuanto al servidor, puedes poner en los datos otro par clave/valor para identificar una acción, o bien buscar por alguno de los que se envían y que no esté en el otro, por ejemplo, si está el nombre sabes que se debe procesar ...

Comment: ... el código relativo al nombre, si está la ciudad, sabes que se debe procesar en el servidor el código relativo a la ciudad. No sé si llegas a entender la lógica del asunto. Si captas la lógica ya todo lo demás es cuestión de organizar el código en el servidor... Si la respuesta desde el servidor es diversa lo mismo, le puedes poner un identificador para saber en el `done` de qué tabla vienen los datos del servidor y saber cómo tratarlos.

Comment: Disculpa que te moleste pero no me sale ningún link del ejemplo solo me sale  [es este]

Comment: No puse el enlace por error. [Esta es la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115728/29967) donde planteo el problema y más abajo está la respuesta explicando lo que decía en mis anteriores comentarios. Lo importante es que puedas captar la idea de la lógica seguida, todo lo demás es cuestión de organizar el código leyendo lo que se haya posteado. Cualquier duda que no encaje en tu contexto, me puedes preguntar. Yo creo que esa lógica sería bastante útil en tu caso.